# How to leverage a local-scope Bigquery ML model in a stored procedure

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using a Bigquery ML model in a stored procedure and I would like to work around the lack of
`CREATE TEMP MODEL`.

Is it possible to write a script that is parallel safe and delete the model in a fail-safe way?

EDIT:
Basically what I want to do is this:

```
CREATE TEMP MODEL mymodel OPTIONS ( MODEL_TYPE='LINEAR_REG') AS
SELECT
  x,
  x + rand() label
FROM
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,100)) x;


SELECT
  *
FROM
  ML.PREDICT( MODEL mymodel,
    (
    SELECT
      x
    FROM
      UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,100)) x
    )
  )
```

But I get a `Query error: TEMP modifier is not allowed with CREATE MODEL.`

Comment: Could you give more context & information on what you have tried so far? Are you trying to implement BQ ML model in a single Stored Procedure?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan I have edited my question. Hope that will help.

Comment: Hi @Francois. As of today, BigQuery ML doesn’t support creating TEMP MODEL. I have raised a feature request on your behalf for this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/224685443). You can click on the star symbol (top-right) to follow and receive updates on the Feature Request. However there is no ETA on when this feature will be implemented.